# error in showing lists of a user and each list has some items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"lists", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

I have a user and when that user login into the system he/she can create lists of items. Now i cannot figure out the problem as per my understanding the code is right.

I'm posting here my code that may help to get the problem

Here is my code
**routes.rb**

```
root 'lists#index'

  resources :users do
    resources :lists , only: [:index, :new, :create] do
        resources :items, only: [:new, :create]
    end
  end

  resources :lists, only: [:destroy]
  resources :items, only: [:destroy]

  get '/signup'  => 'users#new' 
  resources :users

  get '/login'=>'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

**lists_controller.rb**

```
def index
      @lists = List.includes(:items).where(:user_id => session[:user_id]).order('items.priority')
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @list = @user.lists.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @list = @user.lists.new(list_params)
    @list.created_date = DateTime.now

    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.save
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.json { render json: @list.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end
  end
```

**lists/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><h2>Lists Homepage</h2></div>
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <%= link_to "Add List", new_user_list_path(@user), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% if current_user %>
        <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: "delete", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"%>
        <label class="pull-right"><%= current_user.email %></label>
    <% end %>

  </div>
  <div class="new-list"></div>

  <div id="lists">
    <%= render @lists || '' %>
  </div>    

  <%= render 'dialog' %>

</div>
```

Comment: So you want your users to manage their lists, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only logged in users modify only lists they own, you don't need to nest `lists` resources into `users`, so modify your routes.rb so it has:

```
resources :lists , only: [:index, :new, :create] do
  resources :items, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

If you have this, now you should use your `current_user` helper that returns currently logged in user (or `nil` if user isn't logged in) instead of setting `@user` instance variable, so you need to change your `@user` to `current_user` in your controller, for example:

```
@list = current_user.lists.new
```

And the last thing, you should change your links so they aren't related to `user` anymore:

```
<%= link_to "Add list", new_list_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! @MarekLipka

Comment: can you tell me how can i get list_id while saving items using ajax?
AS using this routing methodology , i'm getting same list_id everytime for different lists?